# How to debug slow respond or halt?

Tags: quitting

I try to comments 1.4K+ lines in a C++ function by using `M-;` or rectangle insert string `//`.

Wait for several minutes, Emacs still no respond. I have to kill Emacs.

In this case, how could I locate what cause the Emacs use 100% CPU and looks like do nothing?

Emacs: 25.0

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Do you see the same slow response if you use `M-x comment-region` (after activating the region) instead of `M-;`? If not, then use it.

Comment: Most likely something deep within cc-mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little-known trick... You can send an interrupting debug signal to Emacs with `kill`/`killall`/`pkill`.

```
pkill -USR2 emacs
```

When sent to Emacs, the `USR2` kill signal will interrupt whatever Emacs is doing and drop you to a debugger. From there, you can likely tell what is causing the hang from the stack trace.

Comment: It always stop at `magit-pre-command-hook`.